# Two Dimensions Generated Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a two dimensionnal table. And I'd like to fill it up like a multiplication table with Excel. But I can't find an easy way to do it.
Copying-Pasting the columns or the ligns doesn't work.

```
----- 0 ----- 1 ----- 2 ----- 3 ----- ...

0

1

2

3

....
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following formula into the cell **B2** and drag across and down:

```
=$A2*B$1
```

This assumes your table starts at **A1** as below

```
A    B     C
     0     1
0
1
```

Is that what you were looking for?